# jquery event code in Chrome In full shape not working

Tags: jquery

This javascript code works with Firefox. But in Chrome the "+" sign is added to "000". I tried event.preventDefault(). But it did not make any difference.

```html
<input id="mab" type="text" onKeyPress="return EnsureNumeric(event)">
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#mab').keyup(function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 107) {
      document.getElementById("mab").value = document.getElementById("mab").value + '000';
    }
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get the same behaviour from your code in both Chrome and Firefox; that is, after pressing <kbd>+</kbd> the input value becomes `+000`.

From the context of your question it appears you do not want the `+` to be shown, just the `000`. As such you need to use the `keydown` event instead, as `keyup` is too late in the event chain and the `+` is already added to the value of the input. Try this:

```js
$('#mab').keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 107) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).val(function(i, v) {
      return v + '000';
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="mab" type="text" />
```